# intermittent file not writable error

Tags: cron-job, scheduled-job, filesystem, version

CiviCRM 5.62.1 / Wordpress 6.2.2

I have an intermittent error on the version check action as part of my cron. It'll run fine for a couple of days, then fail, then run again. I suspect an over enthusiastic Wordfence plug-in. I think the issue started around the same time Wordfence left 'training' mode, but I don't know which file to tell Wordfence to ignore.

The other actions on my cron seem to be fine, so I think it's just this one file relating to the version status that's affected.

Any suggestions?

2023-07-09 09:05:03 CiviCRM Update Check
Entity: job Action: version_check
Summary
Finished execution of CiviCRM Update Check with result: Success (1)

2023-07-08 09:05:03 CiviCRM Update Check
Entity: job Action: version_check
Summary
Finished execution of CiviCRM Update Check with result: Failure, Error message: File not writable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version check job tries to write a file in the upload directory, typically `wp-content/uploads/civicrm/upload`   Check the file permissions to make sure those files and directories are writable by the OS user that runs the webserver  (might be `www-data` or `http` etc)

Comment: The specific file is called version-msgs-cache.json:
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/532dda195dddcbdc81898d8ba8de2d96d88d6998/CRM/Utils/VersionCheck.php#L19